# How to keep Kotlin property syntax when defining an Interface?

Tags: android, kotlin, syntax, interface, overriding

CLARIFICATION: property syntax == `val s = supportFragmentManager` as opposed to `val s = getSupportFragmentManager()`

If I'm writing an interface for an Activity class and want to expose a property while retaining the property syntax, how do I do it?

Create a class inheriting AppCompatActivity and implements the following interface.

```
interface MyInterface {
   fun getSupportFragmentManager: FragmentManager // Option 1 Boo!
   val supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager    // Option 2 Yey!
}
```

Option 1 will work just fine.
MyActivity already contains a function called getSupportFragmentManager() so I don't have to implement it.

Option 2 will prompt me to implement the missing property, and doing so I will result in the following

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity(), MyInterface {
    override val supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager
        get() = TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

This will give me an error since there already is a function with the same signature in the class.

```
Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getSupportFragmentManager()Landroidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager;):
    fun <get-supportFragmentManager>(): FragmentManager defined in com.my.project.MyActivity
    fun getSupportFragmentManager(): FragmentManager defined in com.my.project.MyActivity
```

Any ides of how to keep Kotlins property syntax throughout interfaces?

Comment: why don't use both get and set and remove fun from interface? override val supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager
        get() = TODO("Not yet implemented")
 set() = //Your code?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. 
I still get the same clash. 
If I add a getter and I want to return the property with the same name, `supportFragmentManager`, it will try to return itself in a loop.
But more importantly what I need it to realize is that the property is already implemented and use that implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the compiler warnings, and the Accidental override exception you're getting is because of defining both the get function and the original variable itself.

You could do it like this:

```kotlin
interface MyInterface {
   val supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager
}

class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity(), MyInterface {
    override val supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager = FragmentManager(...)
        get() = ... //logic (getter is optional, by default kotlin generates getter itself)
}
```

**PS:** In getter you can use `field` to access the variable aka supportFragmentManager like

```kotlin
get() = field.apply { updateSomthing() }
```

this calls MyActivity.updateSomthing() and return field itself.